# Volume of the region of sphere between two planes.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I want to find the volume of the region of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, between the planes $z=1$ and $z=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

I have used triple integral for calculating this
$$\int _0^{2\pi }\int _{0}^{\frac{\pi }{6}}\int _{0 }^1\:\rho ^2sin\phi \:d\rho \:d\phi \:d\theta $$

Are the limits of integral i have chosen correct??

Edit:
As from the comment, my integral is not correct,  so please clarify what region actually the above integral represents.

Comment: No, they are not correct, as your current integral region touches the origin.

Comment: @Arthur no, i couldn't. Please help. And also if you could clarify, what region does the integral i have chosen is?

Comment: Your region finds the volume of the part of the sphere which is above the _cone_ $\phi=\pi/6$, not the plane $z=\sqrt3/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottom of your region is a horizontal plane which is not the $xy$-plane. This means you should at least consider cylindrical coordinates. For instance,
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{1/2}\int_{\sqrt3/2}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}} r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta
$$
or
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\sqrt3/2}^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-z^2}}r\,dr\,dz\,d\theta
$$
In case you really want spherical coordinates, if we put the radius as the innermost integral, note that it doesn't go from $0$, it goes from wherever $z=\sqrt3/2$, which is to say from $\frac{\sqrt3}{2\cos\phi}$, which is not easy to integrate. If we do $\phi$ first instead, we get
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\sqrt3/2}^1\int_0^{\arccos(2\rho/\sqrt3)}\rho^2\sin\phi\,d\phi\,d\rho\,d\theta
$$
which might look scary at first, but everything turns out pretty nice in the end.

Comment: I got the 1st part!!. Also could you explain about how you are getting  $\frac{\sqrt3}{2\cos\phi}$

Comment: Integrating w.r.t. to $\phi$ first gives a polynomial in the radial variable. Either that or cylindrical coordinates with $r$ first would be the easiest methods.

Comment: @Rkb Given a $\phi$ (and a $\theta$), the ray from the origin in that direction passes the $z=\sqrt3/2$ plane after traveling that far. So that's where we start integrating from.

Comment: @NinadMunshi You're right, I chose the exact wrong order both times. The polar one isn't too bad; $\int r\sqrt{1-r^2}dr$ is quite clearly ripe for substitution. But for spherical it makes a huge difference.

Comment: @Arthur please explain, the limit of $\phi$ in the last integral

Comment: @Rkb Given a $\rho$ (and a $\theta$), the corresponding semicircle arc going down from the $z$-axis hits the $z=\sqrt3/2$ plane at that angle.

Comment: @Arthur so, $\frac{\sqrt3}{2\cos\phi}$ is the angle between $z$ axis and line joining the origin and any point on the spherical arc between$z=1$ and $z=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ ?

Comment: @Rkb Any point on the $z=\sqrt3/2$ plane has a corresponding $\rho$ and $\phi$ coordinate. If the $\rho$ coordinate is fixed (i.e. is the outer integration variable), then the $\phi$ is given by $\arccos(2\rho/\sqrt3)$. If, on the other hand, the $\phi$ is known, the $\rho$ is given by $\frac{\sqrt3}{2\cos\phi}$. This is standard trigonometry, where the hypotenuse is $\rho$, the angle is $\phi$, and the adjacent leg is $\sqrt3/2$.

Comment: @Arthur thanks for making it this clear!!

Answer (score 1):

You do not even need calculus to solve this one. If you visualize, this is a sphere with center at (0,0,0) and radius 1. So the plane z = 1, is tangent to its surface at (0,0,1). The plane $z = \frac{\sqrt3}{2} \lt 1$ is parallel to XY plane and will cut the sphere into  a spherical cap. As you have to find the volume of sphere between these two planes, you really have to find the volume of the spherical cap.

Volume of spherical cap = $\frac {\pi h^2(3R-h)}{3}$ where h is the height of the spherical cap and R is the radius of the sphere. $R = 1, h = (1-\frac{\sqrt3}{2})$. Solving it, you get the volume as $\frac {\pi}{3}(2-\frac{9}{8}\sqrt3)$.

Comment: How you are getting that formula??

Comment: To me, the easiest way to find the formula for the volume of a spherical cap uses this exact integration problem. So "do not even need calculus" is not entirely true.

Comment: My point is that using calculus, formula of a spherical cap is already established and known. If I have planes which are not parallel to each other, and cut the sphere into a more complex way, I would personally use calculus.

Comment: @Rkb, if you want to solve from scratch, use the calculus but this is a more simpler form of two planes cutting a sphere and formula of a spherical cap is already well established. You can see any book or wiki.

Comment: @MathLover at  some point i may need this. But relying on the formula is not the best option. Hence i will go for calculus.

Comment: With you on that. Once we understand it is a spherical cap and you want to do faster, you can as well do $\pi \int_{\sqrt3 / 2}^1 (1-z^2)dz$